# selenium でのループ処理中にエラー発生時も終了しないようにしたい

Tags: python, selenium

seleniumを使用してスクレイピングをしようと考えています。
xpathの一部を変数にしてループさせてテキストを表示しようと考えています。

**わからないこと**
ループで回して取得しようとするのですが、取得する値の数がその時々で変わるので
何回ループを回せばよいのかわかりません。
ですので、該当するxpathが存在しなかった場合、ループを終わりにしたいのですが、うまくいかずエラーが起きてしまいます。
どのようにすればエラー無く終わりにできるか教えていただけるとありがたいです。

**自分のコード**

```
for i in range(1, 100):
    elem_username = browser.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[4]/div/ul/div[{i}]/a/div/div[2]/div/ul[1]/li')
    if elem_username is None:
        break
    else:
        username = elem_username.text
        print(username)
```

**エラー内容**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-199-f0a1904f1817> in <module>
      1 #//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[4]/div/ul/div[2]/a/div/div[2]/div/ul[1]/li
      2 for i in range(1, 100):
----> 3     elem_username = browser.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[4]/div/ul/div[{i}]/a/div/div[2]/div/ul[1]/li')
      4     if elem_username is False:
      5         break

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in find_element_by_xpath(self, xpath)
    392             element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div/td[1]')
    393         """
--> 394         return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
    395 
    396     def find_elements_by_xpath(self, xpath):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in find_element(self, by, value)
    974                 by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
    975                 value = '[name="%s"]' % value
--> 976         return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
    977             'using': by,
    978             'value': value})['value']

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[4]/div/ul/div[20]/a/div/div[2]/div/ul[1]/li"}
  (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.131)
```

**追加**
アドバイスを参考に自身でやってみました。

```
def main():
    try:
        for i in range(1,100):
            elem_username = browser.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[4]/div/ul/div[{i}]/a/div/div[2]/div/ul[1]/li')
            username = elem_username.text
            print(username)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
            
main()
```

発生したエラー内容をpassでスルーしようと考え上記のコード書いてみたのですが、
エラーが発生しました。

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-210-d3324d9fddd1> in main()
      3         for i in range(1,100):
----> 4             elem_username = browser.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[4]/div/ul/div[{i}]/a/div/div[2]/div/ul[1]/li')
      5             username = elem_username.text

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in find_element_by_xpath(self, xpath)
    393         """
--> 394         return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
    395 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in find_element(self, by, value)
    975                 value = '[name="%s"]' % value
--> 976         return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
    977             'using': by,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[4]/div/ul/div[47]/a/div/div[2]/div/ul[1]/li"}
  (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.131)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-210-d3324d9fddd1> in <module>
      8         pass
      9 
---> 10 main()

<ipython-input-210-d3324d9fddd1> in main()
      5             username = elem_username.text
      6             print(username)
----> 7     except NoSuchElementException:
      8         pass
      9 

NameError: name 'NoSuchElementException' is not defined
```

行き詰ってしまいました。
アドバイスを頂けると幸いです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「NoSuchElementException（そのような要素が存在しません）」というエラーが出ていますので、例外処理でこのエラーをキャッチしてループから抜け出す処理を書くといいと思います。
参考までにPythonでの例外処理の方法を載せておきます。
https://note.nkmk.me/python-try-except-else-finally/

<補足>

```
elem_username = browser.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[4]/div/ul/div[{i}]/a/div/div[2]/div/ul[1]/li')
```

ifに到達する前のこの行でエラーが発生してしまっているので、ifブロック内のbreakの処理をする前にプログラムが止まってしまっています。例外処理をすることで、エラーが発生しても処理を続行させることができます。

Comment: 追加で投稿を編集したのでアドバイスを頂けると幸いです。

Comment: NameError: name 'NoSuchElementException' is not definedというエラーが出ていますね。最初からpythonに組み込まれている例外もあるのですが、NoSuchElementExceptionはSelenium特有の例外のため、例外クラスをimportしないと使えないようです。importするか、例外名を省略することで全ての例外をキャッチすることができます。importする場合は以下のリンクを参考にしてください。https://gist.github.com/webgyo/baa72dca8cbee6080b41ea2d14aebaad　省略する場合は 「except NoSuchElementException:」を「except :」としてください。お役に立てれば幸いです。

Comment: 無事エラー無く実行することができました！

Answer (score 1):

[`WebDriver.find_elements_by_xpath()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=find_elements_by_xpath#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_xpath) を使う方法もあります。この場合は `NoSuchElementException` が発生せず、セレクタにマッチする要素がない場合は空リスト(`[]`)が返ります。

```py
def main():
    elem_username = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(
      '//*[@id="__next"]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/ul[1]/div/a[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[1]')
    for e in elem_username:
        username = e.text
        print(username)

main()
```